# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (142, 1)

Tags: machine-learning, python, keras, cnn, image-classification

I'm trying to pass all my images (71 for each class) from folder 'train' to model.fit.
The method ReadImages get these images and resize them (because are too big 4288x2848)....

But when i run my code throws this error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (142, 1)
```

This is my code:

```py
def ReadImages(Path):
    LabelList = list()
    ImageCV = list()
    classes = ["nonPdr", "pdr"]

    # Get all subdirectories
    FolderList = os.listdir(Path)

    # Loop over each directory
    for File in FolderList:
        if(os.path.isdir(os.path.join(Path, File))):
           for index, Image in enumerate(os.listdir(os.path.join(Path, File))):
                # Convert the path into a file
                ImageCV.append(cv2.imread(os.path.join(Path, File) + os.path.sep + Image))
                ImageCV[index] = cv2.resize(ImageCV[index], (700, 600)) 

                # Add a label for each image and remove the file extension
                LabelList.append(classes.index(os.path.splitext(File)[0]))
        else:
            ImageCV.append(cv2.imread(os.path.join(Path, File) + os.path.sep + Image))    
            # Add a label for each image and remove the file extension
            LabelList.append(classes.index(os.path.splitext(File)[0]))
    return ImageCV, LabelList

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same",activation="relu", input_shape=(605,700,3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(128,  kernel_size=(4,4), padding="same",activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='RMSprop', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

data, labels = ReadImages(TRAIN_DIR)
print(data[0])
model.fit(np.array(data), np.array(labels), epochs=10, batch_size=20)

model.save('model.h5')
```

*detail: when I print (data[0]) it return:*

```
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ...
  [1 0 0]
  [2 2 2]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[3 0 0]
  [3 0 0]
  [3 0 0]
  ...
  [2 0 0]
  [2 2 2]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[8 0 0]
  [8 0 0]
  [8 0 0]
  ...
  [2 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 ...

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]]
```

What should I do to fix it? I appreciate any help

Comment: By the looks of it, I am guessing you have two classes with 71 images and when you are doing `np.array(data)` It's treating it as a single array. Could you try `data.values` instead? It should most probably fix the issue.

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: Oh sorry!!! Why do you have lists as the return values? I am assuming you should have a data frame. Can you check `data[0]` now?

Comment: the lists return all the imgs from folder... And the return of data[0] is up on question. Can you be more clear?

Comment: Apologies for not being clear! I want to check your shape of `data[0]` and `type(data[0])`. If `type(data[0])` is np.array, then try doing `np.stack(data)`.

Comment: the type is np.array, and I put np.stack(data)... It return the follow error: ValueError: all input arrays must have the same shape

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98245/discussion-between-danny-and-gilberto).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def ReadImages(Path):
    LabelList = list()
    ImageCV = list()
    classes = ["nonPdr", "pdr"]

   # Get all subdirectories
   FolderList = [f for f in os.listdir(Path) if not f.startswith('.')]
   print(FolderList)

   # Loop over each directory
   for File in FolderList:
      for index, Image in enumerate(os.listdir(os.path.join(Path, File))):
          # Convert the path into a file
          ImageCV.append(cv2.resize(cv2.imread(os.path.join(Path, File) + os.path.sep + Image), (600,700)))
          LabelList.append(classes.index(os.path.splitext(File)[0])) 

   return ImageCV, LabelList
```

A bit of change to your code after discussion in the chat room.